# Vigorous shaking for HFR interrupted mating

Tags: microbiology, molecular-genetics, plasmids

I am trying to reproduce *E. coli* interrupted mating using an HFR strain, and I read that the cultures should be vigorously shaken  at times to interrupt the DNA transfer from the F+(HFR) donors to the F- cells.

How vigorously(I'm OK with a qualitative answer) should I shake the culture for optimal results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember doing this experiment many years ago in an undergraduate practical where we used vigorous vortexing of culture samples in glass tubes to achieve interruption and separation.

According to [Griffiths AJF, Gelbart WM, Miller JH, *et al.* **Modern Genetic Analysis**. Bacterial Conjugation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21351/):

> ... sampling is accomplished by using a kitchen blender to separate
>   the joined cells, resulting in interrupted conjugation.